# Create Custom Content Type in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have crated an SPFx app using this link https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package 
i have created a list, a content type and a few columns in it.
as an upgrade to the app i create another list. all of these things works fine. 
Now i want to create a new content type, add a few more site columns , attach the site columns to the Content type (existing and new).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you did it previously for your contenttype in the same elements.xml file.
You can have multiple Fiels, ContentTypes and ListInstances in one elements.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Velin,
actually i did that but the issue is even a small mistake in the xml  cause the app package to fail and it is unknown until i deploy the package.
it just dont install the package if there is any issue. but it takes time to diagnose what wrong in the xml files.

Comment: You can have a look at sample I recently uploaded https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-provision-assets. I added some advanced xml definitions so you do not lose time and trial-fail when you add components to the elements.xml file.